# How to properly use expose-gc in meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I tried

1. `NODE_OPTIONS="--expose-gc"` - fails with an error that the flag is not supported.
2. `TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--expose-gc"` - does not err, but `global.gc` is undefined in the app.

Meteor v1.8.0_1

Comment: Interesting, because `console.log(process.argv)` does not show anything that is passed via `TOOL_NODE_FLAGS` but this is also maybe due to the internals of how the `meteor` start script works. You can play around with it, it is located at `~/.meteor/`

Comment: Related gh issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10460